# Mono to Stereo Pan Knob

Tags: audio, potentiometer, stereo

I am trying to make a small box to take the mono audio output form my analog synth and run it through a panning knob so I can control where in the stereo mix the mono signal is placed. The goal is to be able to easily change the L/R pan of the synth in the output during performance. I am aware of Pan Pot circuits like [this one](http://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/pan-pot.html) but that seems above my current electronics ability right now.

Would it be possible to instead do something much more simple like getting a dual gang pot like [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3392), wire the mono signal to both sets of leads so that the one channel increases as the other one decreases? Or would this cause the center position to have less volume than the full right or left position?

In short, is building a full Pan Pot circuit my only option or is there something more simple I can do instead?

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDWN8h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R values subject to change depending on Source impedance and load impedance of mixer.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sunnyskyguy EE75:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhEO8h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The simplest passive way that also allows both at full volume in center is to have the mono signal split to TWO independent pots that each just go to their individual outputs.  I know its two knobs but thats the simplest passive way to have both at max on both sides.  Could put them right against eachother in the housing so one hand can control both at once. Allows to modulate one side without effecting the other too.